# How to input values in list using input function only in python?

Tags: python, list, input

I want to make inputs in a list using input command  here is my code
please see it

```
n=int(input())
li=[]
i=0
for i in range(0,n,1):
    li[i]=int(input())
li
```

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: i wanna input  n no of values in list

Comment: and is there anything wrong with your code so far?

Comment: The `append` function is optimised for efficiency, there’s no harm in using it.

Comment: Based on input styles,

 1. N 1 2 3 4

    N, *li = list(map(int, input().split()))

 2. N 
    1 2 3 4

    N = int(input())
    li = list(map(int, input().split())) 
    // wrapped in list() because in python 3 map will return generator

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions for this,

If the input is on the same line and space separated,

```
li = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

If the input is on new lines,

```
li = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
n = 3
mylist = [int(input('Type value: ')) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can input n number of inputs at a time:
For example: you have

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

then, you can simply take input in one line as below:

```
List = map(int, input.split(" "))
```

I hope it helped you... you have any queries post your queries.